# Enabling Google Play Services Programmatically

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to enable Google Play Services on my device when my app starts. `GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` displays an "Update Google Play services" dialog, but when I select Update, GPS remains disabled. Perhaps it can only be updated programmatically but not enabled?

There is no Google account on the device which may be relevant.